# selecting few rows by index from dask dataframe?

Tags: dask

```
df = dd.read_csv('csv',usecols=fields,skip_blank_lines=True)
len(df.iloc[0:5])
```

The above code raises

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

tried ix loc but unable select rows based on index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dask.dataframe does not support `iloc`.  Generally it's quite hard to do access any particular row in a csv file without first reading it all into memory.

However if you only want a few of the rows at the top then I recommend using the `.head()` method

```
>>> df.head()
```

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is to create the index as a column, i.e. `df_index`, in your csv file and use it like so:

```
selection = (df[ df['df_index'].isin( list_of_indexes ) ]).compute()
```